# could not load libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib because image not found

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I have xcode 4.5 with 6.1 sdk.

I updated my iphone to iOS 7.0.

opened my project on xcode selected my device and clicked run.

I got the following error:

> dyld: could not load inserted library '/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib' because image not found

image not found error is a new one didn't find anywhere on the internet. It's not the old libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib error people got when they updated their devices with earlier versions of Xcode.

I did link or/and copied developer folder from "5.1.1 (9B206)" to "7.0 (11A465)".

But still getting same error.

Does anyone managed to run on iOS 7 device from xCode 4.5? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that to do device debugging on iPhone with iOS7 you will require to use XCode 5 with iOS7 toolchain. XCode 4.5 is older release and may not have the toolchain for latest iOS7.

Comment: May be you are right. please add the following to your answer so I can accept it. Debugging want work. but if you stopped the app from Xcode. then relaunch it from the device it will work. because it is installed.

Comment: It works because your app will not be debugging anymore. Debug fails to load the dynamic library. This is contradicting your question. The answer I have given is correct for your question. To accept it or not is your choice :)

Comment: you can say: you can still run the app by relaunch it from device.

Answer (score 4):

For those who have not yet installed Xcode 4.5, the app can still be debugged by Attaching to Process. Try to debug directly from xcode first. By the time debug fails, the app will still have been installed on the device. Then run the app on the device, and Attach to Process from Xcode.